# Ejabberd : Disable request Accept/Cancel to chat with another user

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Currently, I'm developing a iOS/Web App but when testing the XMPP server with iMessage and Adium I see that they request each other to be able to chat. as well a Certificate Acceptance. I haven't start with XMPP development on Web and iOS. Will I still need to follow this steps? there is a way that everyone can chat with everyone?

Answer (score 1):

In XMPP, people request each other to see the others in the contact list and to see the presence.

However, nothing in XMPP prevent a user from chatting from a user that is not in your roster. If you UI allow to start a chat based on a specific user JID, they can chat together.

The default is thus already to let everyone chat with everyone.